# How to get the first address of initialized data segment

Tags: c, linux

my program is working on linux using gcc. Through the manual page, I find edata, which represent the first address **past** the **end** of the initialized data segment.
But I want know **the first address of initialized data segment**
How can I get it?

I have tried treating **etext** as the first address of initialized data segment. Then I got a segment fault when I increase the address and access the variable stored in it. I think some address space between etext and edata was not mapped into virtual memory. Is that right?

Comment: How do you find `edata`? Can't you use the same technique to find `data`? And why not simply read the binary file and find the `data` segment? What I'm most curious about though, is *why* you need it? What is the original problem you are trying to solve? (Related reading: ["What is the XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @JoachimPileborg. I search the question and only find edata, etext, end. this is why I ask for help here.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg isn't my question clear? I have read related document and searched for it. If you can't answer it, just go away. or, I will thank you. Do not judge me or ask why I want to know it. that is stupid

Comment: I would guess that the data segment begins at the next page boundary after `etext`, at least it does so according to the linker script.

Comment: The question is clear, but the *reason* for the question is not. There might be other solutions to solve your problem (the *original* problem, not the one you ask about here), but without knowing the original problem it's impossible to say. Please read the link about the XY problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just wanna know the first address of initialized data segment. maybe there are other solutions to my program. I still wanna know the answer

Comment: @fanux - We are just curious if you have found some way to *use* that information. Joachim and I obviously haven't.

Comment: So it's just curiosity and experimentation, no underlying reason? Have you tried reading the executable file, and parse the segments and meta-data there? Does it say anything about the `.data` segment? Also note that there might actually be *two* data segments, one for read-only data (`.rodata`) that is put into the text segment, and the modifiable data segment (`.data`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on your linker scripts. For example on some platforms you have the symbol `__bss_start` at the beginning of BSS. It's a symbol without any data associated with it, you can get a pointer to it by `extern` declaring a variable with that name (only for the sake of taking the address of that variable). For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char __bss_start;

int main()
{
    printf("%p\n", &__bss_start);

    return 0;
}
```

You find this by looking in the linker script, for example in `/usr/lib/ldscripts/elf_x64_64.x`:

```
.data           :
{
  *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
  SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
}
.data1          : { *(.data1) }
_edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
__bss_start = .;  /*  <<<<< this is what you're looking for /*
.bss            :
{
 *(.dynbss)
 *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
 *(COMMON)
 /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
    _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
    .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
    FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
    pad the .data section.  */
 . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
}
```

You can also see the `edata` you mentioned, but as `edata` is not reserved for the implementation (the `PROVIDE` means only to create this symbol if it otherwise isn't used) you should probably use `_edata` instead.

If you want the address to the start of the `data` section you could modify the linker script:

```
__data_start = . ;
.data           :
{
  *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
  SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
}
.data1          : { *(.data1) }
_edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
__bss_start = .;  /*  <<<<< this is what you're looking for /*
.bss            :
{
 *(.dynbss)
 *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
 *(COMMON)
 /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
    _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
    .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
    FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
    pad the .data section.  */
 . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
}
```

You probably want to make a copy of the linker script (look for the right one in `/usr/lib/ldscripts`, they are different depending on what kind of output you're targeting) and supply it when you compile:

```
gcc -o execfile source.c -Wl,-T ldscript
```

Another option if you don't want to modify the linker script could be to use the `__executable_start` and parse the ELF headers (hoping that the executable is sufficiently linearly mapped)

As for `_etext`, it is the end of the `text` section (you can read that in the linker script as well, but I didn't include it in the excerpt), but the `text` section is followed by `rodata`, trying to write there is probably going to segfault.

Comment: But what I expect is a function or a variable or a macro... Thank you

Comment: The variable **__data_start** and **data_start** can be **directly** used in the program without being defined in ldscript. They are both the first address of initialized data segment and their values are the same. Their usage is just like etext and edata. This may only work on Linux using gcc, because I haven't test it on other compiler and platform.

Comment: @fanux It looks like these symbols originate from another place than linker scripts. It actually relies on how sections are combined to form the data section in the executable, `__data_start` is the first in the section of `crt0.o` which makes it be placed first in the data section of the executable. Anyway any such features are dependent on the compiler/linker in use - you would have to investigate how to do it if you're going to use another compiler/linker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the linux tool `size` (binutils package in Debian/Ubuntu).

Example

```
size -A /usr/bin/gcc
```

results in

```
/usr/bin/gcc  :
section                size      addr
.interp                  28   4194928
.note.ABI-tag            32   4194956
.note.gnu.build-id       36   4194988
.gnu.hash               240   4195024
.dynsym                4008   4195264
.dynstr                2093   4199272
.gnu.version            334   4201366
.gnu.version_r          160   4201704
.rela.dyn               720   4201864
.rela.plt              3240   4202584
.init                    14   4205824
.plt                   2176   4205840
.text                384124   4208016
.fini                     9   4592140
.rodata              303556   4592160
.eh_frame_hdr          8540   4895716
.eh_frame             50388   4904256
.gcc_except_table       264   4954644
.tbss                    16   7052632
.init_array              16   7052632
.fini_array               8   7052648
.jcr                      8   7052656
.data.rel.ro           3992   7052672
.dynamic                480   7056664
.got                    216   7057144
.got.plt               1104   7057384
.data                  2520   7058496
.bss                  80976   7061024
.gnu_debuglink           12         0
Total                849310
```